# How to Change icon color according to sqlite database?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created a database and it includes a favorite list,I want to get the data whether the item is on the favorite list to render it on the screen

```
icon: Icon ( await DBProvider.db
                          .searchFavItem(widget._items[index].idItem)
                      ? Icons.favorite
                      : Icons.favorite_border),
```

However,I got an error message "The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'."

I don't know how to add a function in this kind of statement.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue you would need to load the `async` value first and then pass that returned value to the `Icon Widget`, this is because the `icon` property of the `Icon Widget` is not expecting an `async` value. So you will not be able to use `await` here.

One way to this is with the `FutureBuilder` Widget, other ways include using `State Management` to manage the state of the UI while the data loads.